# Add comments to posts = undefined local variable or method `post' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

Hi there I have an error like this                                `undefined local variable or method 'post' for #<#<Class:0x007ffc40469ad0>:0x007ffc40461088>`

I don't understand because I create a partial in post which names `_comments.html.erb`

```
<p class="text-center">Poster un commentaire</p>
      <%= simple_form_for [post, post.comments.new] do |f| %>
        <%= f.error_notification %>
        <%= f.input :content, label: "Commentaire"%>
        <%= f.submit "Envoyer", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
```

and it render like that `<% render 'comments' %>`

The undefined method is in this line `<%= simple_form_for [post, post.comments.new] do |f| %>`

the model post is `has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy`

the model post is `has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy`

the model comment is `belongs_to :user
                    belongs_to :post`

The route is 
      resources :posts do
        resources :categories
          resources :comments
      end

Comments controller is

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

before_action :set_post

def create
  @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
  @comment.user_id = current_user.id

  if @comment.save
    flash[:success] = "You commented the hell out of that post!"
    redirect_to :back
  else
    flash[:alert] = "There is a problem with your comment"
    render root_path
  end
end

def destroy
  @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])

  @comment.destroy
  flash[:success] = "Comment deleted :("
  redirect_to root_path
end

private

def set_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
end

def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :post_id, :user_id)
end
end
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating the following:

`<%= simple_form_for [post, post.comments.new] do |f| %>`

with this:

`<%= simple_form_for [@post, @post.comments.new] do |f| %>`

Comment: it works but the render `<% render 'comments' %>`displays nothing.. Do you know why?

Comment: You should use `<%= render 'comments' %>`, not `<% render 'comments' %>`. Notice the missing `=` sign?

Comment: I try to iterate 
              `<ul class="list-unstyled">
                <% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
                <li>

                      <h5><% comment.content %></h5>
                  <% end %>
                </li>
              </ul>`
but nothing appears when I try to give a comment

Comment: Again, use <%= comment.content %>. You need = sign to print something.

Comment: Yes thank you I did it, I don't understand why I miss it everytime